# SQLite Android tables with foreign keys support and uploading to remote server not working

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to upload some data from two different tables from one SQLite database in Android, onto a MySQL server.

When I had one table, it uploaded just fine, but now nothing gets uploaded at all. My challenge is getting the foreign key relationship to work, and then uploading data from the two tables onto the server.

Below is what I've tried so far. First class called `ResponseDetails` with its own create statement:

```
public class ResponseDetailTable {


// table response_detail tags
  public static final String TABLE_RESPONSE_DETAIL = "response_detail";
  public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
  public static final String KEY_ANSWER_TEXT = "answer_text";
  public static final String KEY_QUESTION_ID = "question_id";
  public static final String KEY_ANSWER_ID = "answer_id";
  public static final String KEY_RESPONSE_ID = "response_id";


  //table response tags
  public static final String TABLE_RESPONSE = "response"; 

  public static final String KEY_COL_ID = "_id";



// Database creation SQL statement for response_detail table
  private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RESPONSE_DETAIL = "create table " 
      + TABLE_RESPONSE_DETAIL
      + "(" 
      + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
      + KEY_QUESTION_ID + " integer,"
      + KEY_ANSWER_TEXT + " text not null, " 
      + KEY_ANSWER_ID + " integer ," 
      + KEY_RESPONSE_ID + " integer ,"
      + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_RESPONSE_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_RESPONSE+" ("+KEY_COL_ID+") "
      + ");";
```

Second class called ResponseTable with it's create statement:

```
public class ResponseTable {

// table response tags

      public static final String TABLE_RESPONSE = "response"; 
      public static final String KEY_COL_ID = "_id";
      public static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
      public static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "lastName";
      public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
      public static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER = "phoneNumber";
      public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";



    // Database creation SQL statement for response table
      private static final String CREATE_TABLE_RESPONSE = "create table " 
          + TABLE_RESPONSE
          + "(" 
          + KEY_COL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
          + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " text not null, " 
          + KEY_LAST_NAME + " text not null, "
          + KEY_EMAIL + " text not null, "
          + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER + " text not null, "
          + KEY_DATE + " varchar "
          + ");";
```

And finally my php script:

```
<?php


$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);


//create connection

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pwd = "";
$db = "webservice";

//create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

// Check connection

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
die("Failed to connect to MySQL :" . mysqli_connect_error());

}else { echo "Connection was ok!" ;}

        foreach ($obj as $id => $jsons) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO response_detail(question_id, answer_text,answer_id, response_id ) VALUES ('".$jsons->{'question_id'}"', '".$jsons->{'answer_text'}"', '".$jsons->{'answer_id'}"','".$jsons->{'response_id'}"')";



        mysqli_query($con, $query); 


        //$sql = "INSERT INTO response(firstName, lastName, email, PhoneNumber, date) VALUES (".$jsons->firstName.",".$jsons->lastName.",".$jsons->email.",".$jsons->phoneNumber.",".$jsons->date.")";


        //mysqli_query($con, $sql); 

            }

mysqli_close($con);


//$post = $array(1);
header('COntent-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('post'=>$post));



?>
```

My db helper class with the PRAGMA COMMAND  looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.mabongar.survey/databases/";

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "responsetable.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
  public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
  private Context mycontext;


  public DatabaseHandler(Context context) throws IOException {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);



  }

  // Method is called during creation of the database
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    ResponseDetailTable.onCreate(database);
    ResponseTable.onCreate(database);
  }



// Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
  // e.g. if you increase the database version
  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
      int newVersion) {
    ResponseDetailTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);

    ResponseTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
  }

  private boolean checkdatabase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            //checkdb =     SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }
        return checkdb;
    }

  public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        if (!myDataBase.isReadOnly()) {
            // Enable foreign key constraints
            myDataBase.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
            }

  }

  public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if(dbexist) {

        } else {
             this.getReadableDatabase();

         copydatabase();
        }
    }   

  private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.mabongar.survey/databases/responsetable.db");

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }
```

}

**So what isn't working is:**

1. The foreign key column is never displayed when I execute the select everything query on the `response_detail` table.However, when I drop the FK constraint and just use it as a normal column and add values, it is displayed.
2. None of the SQLite data is uploaded to my MySQL server.I'm not sure how to write the nested for each loop for both tables.

**EDIT :**

First table-**ResponseDetail class** has data inserted from a quiz where each question downloaded from the server appears on it's fragment with a viewpager.

The code is really long,so i only showed the part where the responses are sent when you hit the 'next' button.

```
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (question.getWidgetId() == 1) {

                rg = (RadioGroup) relative1.findViewById(R.id.radioGrp1);

                if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {




                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(c2, "Please Select Answer", 0).show();
                }


            }else if (question.getWidgetId() == 2) {

                spinner = (Spinner) relative1.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

                //get spinner selected value
                String spinner_text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                question_id = (Integer) question_txt.getTag();
                answer_id = (Integer) spinner.getTag();
                //get question_id for this widget

                que_id = String.valueOf(question_id);



                //get answer_id for this widget
                ans_id = String.valueOf(answer_id);


                // send values to db
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(ResponseDetailTable.KEY_ANSWER_TEXT, spinner_text);

                values.put(ResponseDetailTable.KEY_QUESTION_ID, que_id);

                values.put(ResponseDetailTable.KEY_ANSWER_ID,
                         ans_id);

                getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext()
                        .getContentResolver()
                        .insert(ResponseContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);

            } 
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true);
        }

    });
```

**EDIT :**

The other class **ResponseTable** gets populated from a user contact form on a separate activity.

```
public class FormActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{
private Button btnDone;
private EditText cfName, clName,cEmail, cPhoneNum;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_activity);
cfName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_fName);
        clName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_lName);
        cEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Email);
        cPhoneNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Phone);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

     switch (v.getId()) {


        case R.id.btnDone1:

            boolean sent = true;

            try {
            String user_fname = cfName.getText().toString();
            String user_lname = clName.getText().toString();
            String user_email = cEmail.getText().toString();
            String user_phoneNum = cPhoneNum.getText().toString();
            String date = txtDate.getText().toString();

            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            cv.put(ResponseTable.KEY_FIRST_NAME, user_fname);
            cv.put(ResponseTable.KEY_LAST_NAME, user_lname);
            cv.put(ResponseTable.KEY_EMAIL, user_email);
            cv.put(ResponseTable.KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, user_phoneNum);
            cv.put(ResponseTable.KEY_DATE, date);


            getApplicationContext()
            .getContentResolver()
            .insert(ResponseContentProvider.CONTENT_URI1,
                    cv);    



            } catch (Exception e) {
                sent = false;
            } finally {
                if (sent) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "saved !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                }
            }

          //  new   UserContacts().execute("http://10.0.2.2/webservice/post_data.php");

            Intent intent = new Intent (this, SubmitActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           // FormActivity.this.finish();

            break;

     }

}
```

i'm basically trying to link each user with their responses (response_details).So i'm trying to get the FK 'response_id' from ResponseDetailTable to refer to the primary key of the other ResponseTable(user contacts table)

Comment: After you connect to SQLite, you need to issue a pragma command to turn on FK constraints - they are off by default. [See here](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable).

Comment: Also feel free to explain what "not working" means exactly.

Comment: Hi @halfer, i already issued that command in my code in my db helper class.But when i query my database to read everything from the two tables, the response_id column(FK column) is not displayed along with the other rows from the response detail table.If i try to remove the foreign key constraint and just add random values to it then read everything from the same table,it is displayed this time.So i'm guessing there's something i missed with setting up the FK relationship between the two tables.I edited my code above to show the pragma command.

Comment: @laalto I edited my question to explain what isn't working exactly.

Comment: It would be better if you ask questions one a time here - it simplifies the problem statement, but it also makes the question more useful to others in the future. Concentrate, therefore, on just the FK issue first.

Comment: It sounds like data is not getting into your SQLite table. What is the SQL `INSERT` that you are using? Edit that into your question. Then, run it, and ensure all the FK constraints would not be violated by running it.

Comment: Thank you for that edit and for your time also.I really appreciate it.I din't realize i was too wordy in my question.It's even easier to understand now.And i edited the question again with the inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Put this on create of the dbhelper (Sqlite helper)

```
db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
```